# Listen for wheel down and Mount and Unmount event-listener

Tags: reactjs

I want to add an event listener for a scroll wheel event down and up, where I route to different pages based on the scroll up or scroll down, and to mount and unmount this event listener.

```
pageDown = () => {[redirect to page down]}

render() {
  window.addEventListener('wheel', function(e) {
    if (e.deltaY > 0) {
      this.pageDown();
    }
});

return ([Some Code])}
```

I was using this and whilst the redirecting on my site was good initially after a few scrolls up and down the redirection would become confused and bug out. I figured this was maybe because of no mounting/unmounting.

I've tried the below, removing the previous event-listener in the render().

```
componentDidMount() {
  window.addEventListener('wheel', function(e) {
    if (e.deltaY > 0) {
      this.pageDown();
    }
  });
}

componentWillUnmount() {
  window.removeEventListener('wheel', function(e) {
    if (e.deltaY > 0) {
      this.pageDown();
    }
  });
}

render(){return ([Some code])}
```

However, when I try to scroll down react warns me `this.pageDown()` is not a function and I'm not sure why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`this` inside your event handler references the `function` itself, not your component.

A classic solution is the following:

```
var self = this;
window.addEventListener('wheel', function(e) {
  if (e.deltaY > 0) {
    self.pageDown();
  }
});
```

However, a better solution is to use arrow functions:

```
window.addEventListener('wheel', e => {
  if (e.deltaY > 0) {
    this.pageDown();
  }
});
```

Also note that you are not removing the function correctly, you should remove exactly the same function you are adding (the same function reference):

```
onWheel = e => {
  if (e.deltaY > 0) {
    this.pageDown();
  }
};

componentDidMount() {
   window.addEventListener('wheel', this.onWheel);
}

componentWillUnmount() {
   window.removeEventListener('wheel', this.onWheel);
}
```